# kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters

Tags: linux, ssh, android-source, repo

When I try to init the AOSP repo, the foloowing mistakes occurred

```
Get ssh:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/repo
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How to fix this error and init the repo?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585730/13317 ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bot  Seems like enough info to me

Comment: I think there is enough info!